# HTML5 Canvas changing image color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, html5-canvas

I am using jquery slider to change my image color from Blue to red (with range of -100 to 100), by tinting it. It means when the slider value is 0, the image should look normal (default one) and changes based on the value of the slider from blue (-100) to (100).

In my local I am able to load the image into my canvas (for some reason the image is not loaded on jsfiddle).

The main issue is the current code does not modify the color as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/q3qw1c0o/3/

```
   $(function(){

    var currentValue = $('#currentValue');


   $( "#slider" ).slider({
        range: "max",
        min: -100,
        max: 100,
        value: 0,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#sliderValue" ).val( ui.value );
            $(ui.value).val($('#sliderValue').val());
            changeIt(ui.value);
        }
        });

    $("#sliderValue").change(function() {
    $("#slider").slider("value" , $(this).val())
    });

});

 var x; //drawing context
var width;
var height;
var fg;
var buffer

window.onload = function() {
    var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myDrawing');
    // Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
    if(drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
        // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context
        x = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
        width = x.canvas.width;
        height = x.canvas.height;

        fg = new Image();
        fg.src = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshow/transport/256/Sportscar-car-icon.png';

        // to tint the image, draw it first
        x.drawImage(fg,0,0);

    }
}

    function changeIt(value) {


        // create offscreen buffer, 
        buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
        buffer.width = fg.width;
        buffer.height = fg.height;
        bx = buffer.getContext('2d');

        // fill offscreen buffer with the tint color
        bx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + value + ', 0, ' + (255 - value) + ')';
        bx.fillRect(0,0,buffer.width,buffer.height);

        // destination atop makes a result with an alpha channel identical to fg, but with all pixels retaining their original color *as far as I can tell*
        bx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
        bx.drawImage(fg,0,0);

                //then set the global alpha to the amound that you want to tint it, and draw the buffer directly on top of it.
        x.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        x.drawImage(buffer,0,0);

    }
```

Please have a look.

Comment: I ran the code you supplied and I am getting an error 'theImage' is undefined, are you not setting a variable called theImage?

Comment: @SythnetP sorry just edited the post. thats not the issue I just missed to set the correct var names. fixed now.

Comment: Do you know how to use the console on any browser? I just ran it again and I am getting x.canvas.width is not defined

Comment: @SythnetP  I dont get any error on console! anyway My point is the function changeIt which does not work properly and as expected. can you see where the issue is?

Comment: You're putting the destination image on top of the original layer, causing you to lose the original pixel data using globalAlpha. You can use alpha channel for the fill style (rgba), and it will get you a bit farther, but I strongly suggest you use pixel manipulation as @markE has described.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Here's one way using `getImageData` to manipulate the hue of each image pixel:**

- Use `getImageData` to fetch the RGBA color data of each pixel
- Convert the RGBA color to HSL color. The H in HSL means Hue which is what we normally think of as "color".
- If the Hue of an original pixel is red-ish (Hue<30 or Hue>300) then shift the hue by the amount specified in your range control. If you want to shift from red to blue, then your slider should shift the color (Hue) from 0 to -.33.

Note: `getImageData` requires that the image originate on the same domain as the webpage or else you will get a cross-domain security error.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var imgData,data,originalData;

$myslider=$('#myslider');
$myslider.attr({min:0,max:33}).val(0);
$myslider.on('input change',function(){
  var value=parseInt($(this).val());
  HueShift(30,300,-value/100);
});

var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshow/transport/256/Sportscar-car-icon.png";
function start(){
  cw=canvas.width=img.width;
  ch=canvas.height=img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch);
  data=imgData.data;
  imgData1=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch);
  originalData=imgData1.data;

}



function HueShift(hue1,hue2,shift){

  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4){
    red=originalData[i+0];
    green=originalData[i+1];
    blue=originalData[i+2];
    alpha=originalData[i+3];

    // skip transparent/semiTransparent pixels
    if(alpha<230){continue;}

    var hsl=rgbToHsl(red,green,blue);
    var hue=hsl.h*360;

    // change redish pixels to the new color
    if(hue<30 || hue>300){


      var newRgb=hslToRgb(hsl.h+shift,hsl.s,hsl.l);
      data[i+0]=newRgb.r;
      data[i+1]=newRgb.g;
      data[i+2]=newRgb.b;
      data[i+3]=255;
    }
  }    
  ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
}






////////////////////////
// Helper functions
//

function rgbToHsl(r, g, b){
  r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
  var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
  var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;
  if(max == min){
    h = s = 0; // achromatic
  }else{
    var d = max - min;
    s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
    switch(max){
      case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
      case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
      case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
    }
    h /= 6;
  }
  return({ h:h, s:s, l:l });
}

function hslToRgb(h, s, l){
  var r, g, b;
  if(s == 0){
    r = g = b = l; // achromatic
  }else{
    function hue2rgb(p, q, t){
      if(t < 0) t += 1;
      if(t > 1) t -= 1;
      if(t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
      if(t < 1/2) return q;
      if(t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
      return p;
    }
    var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
    var p = 2 * l - q;
    r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
    g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
    b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
  }
  return({
    r:Math.round(r * 255),
    g:Math.round(g * 255),
    b:Math.round(b * 255),
  });
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Change the slider to change the car color</h4>
<input id=myslider type=range min=0 max=100 value=0><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer. Can you please update the range from -100 to 100

Comment: You're welcome! Here's how to go from red to blue using the range of -100 to 100: https://jsfiddle.net/2cq8rf4n/ Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks again, so the 0 value is the normal image right?

Comment: If you want to go from the original (red) color to blue, then the original image must be at either end of the range (either -100 or 100). You can set the range control to 0, which would be purple.  ;-)

Comment: cant get it to work for the following image! https://www.dropbox.com/s/upsvo18h17cgzki/shape.png?dl=0 not able to load the image to the canvas. moreover its yellowish so the -100 needs to make it red and 100 needs to make it blue! but in my local it just changes some part of the image color! :/

Comment: (1) Image not appearing == You must wait for the image to fully load using `fg.onload`. (2) If you want to make a more generalized image editor that works with different images, you must select which hue range that you want changed so that the unselected hues on the image are not also changed. To do this, you could  let the user click the image on the color they want to change. Fetch the hue of the clicked color. Then instead of `if(hue<30 || hue>300)` you could change a small range around the selected hue like this: `if(Math.abs(selectedHue-hue)<30)`.

Comment: is there any possibility to direct set particular colour for example current default image colour is red now I want to directory change to white or randomly what should be passed value  ` HueShift(30,300,-value/100);` function ? please help for this minor issue

Comment: Why not use a matrix to multiply the RGB just?

Comment: The RGB(A) format embeds the lightness and color-saturation properties while HSL allows you to isolate just the "color" (==hue). You can change "color" with RGB(A), but HSL makes the calculation more direct.